File descriptor is not closed but moved
According to man bash the redirection 6>&- should close the file descriptor 6, but it seems it is only moved (to 10 in this case). Why is this so?
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
set -u                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
func() {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    echo fck0 >&10                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        echo fck1 >&6                                                                                                                                                                                              
        echo fck2 >&10                                                                                                                                                                                             
    } 6>&-                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    echo yes >&6                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
func 6>&1

Output:
/tmp/t2: line 6: 10: Bad file descriptor
/tmp/t2: line 8: 6: Bad file descriptor
fck2
yes


Obviously the output of fck2 is unexpected.
The same behaviour can be observed if {varname} syntax is used.
It works if a subshell is used, i.e. ( … ) 6>&-, though.

See the end of this answer. Relevant? The same shell process that has to make echo fck1 >&6 fail, has to make echo yes >&6 succeed later, so it has to keep the descriptor open somewhere. The "somewhere" is fd 10 in this case. It's not an answer because it's just my guess.

"It works if a subshell is used" – see the first sentence of this answer. In this case the subshell is a process different than the one that is going to make echo yes >&6 succeed later.

@KamilMaciorowski, sounds reasonable, although the effect is quite disturbing.
